# Calculating the amount of change due

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am noob to Java and I am trying write a program that gives the amount of change given two dollar inputs. I cannot figure out what is going on.  I am specifically having trouble trying to output the coinage. So for example if a person owed $654.32 and paid $987 their change should be $332.68 which would be 2 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, and 3 pinnies.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;


public class CorrectChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        BigDecimal AmtDue;      
        BigDecimal AmtPaid;


        NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

        //User enters the amount that the customer owes
        System.out.println("Enter the amount below that is due to be paid.");
        System.out.print("$");
            AmtDue = input.nextBigDecimal();

            //Converts user's input into the currency format
            AmtDue = AmtDue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                double dAmtDue = AmtDue.doubleValue();
                    String eAmtDue = n.format(dAmtDue);

        //User enters the amount that the customer paid     
        System.out.println("Enter the amount below that has been paid.");
        System.out.print("$");
            AmtPaid = input.nextBigDecimal();

            //Converts user's input into the currency format
            AmtPaid = AmtPaid.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                double dAmtPaid = AmtPaid.doubleValue();
                    String eAmtPaid = n.format(dAmtPaid);

            //Checks to see if the amount paid is more than the amount owed
            if (AmtDue.compareTo(AmtPaid)> 0){
                double dBal = AmtDue.subtract(AmtPaid).doubleValue();
                String eBal = n.format(dBal);
                System.out.println("You still owe: " + eBal.toString());
            }

            //Checks to see if the amount owed is more than the amount paid
            if (AmtDue.compareTo(AmtPaid)< 0){
                int cBal = (AmtPaid.compareTo(AmtDue)*100);
                double dBal = AmtPaid.subtract(AmtDue).doubleValue();
                String eBal = n.format(dBal);


                    int DolBills = (int) (dBal / 1);
                    dBal = dBal % 1;

                    int quarters = (int) (dBal / 25);
                    dBal = dBal % 25;

                    int dimes = (int) (cBal / 10);
                    cBal = cBal % 10;

                    int nickles = (int) (cBal / 5);
                    cBal = cBal % 5;

                    //pennies = (int) (dBal / 100);
                    //dBal = dBal % 100;

                System.out.println("You owe a balance of " + eAmtDue.toString() + ". Since you paid the amount of " + eAmtPaid.toString() + " your change is " + eBal.toString());
                System.out.println("Your change amount is as follows:\n" +
                    "\t" + DolBills + " $1 dollar bills \n" +
                    "\t" + quarters + " quarters \n" +
                    "\t" + dimes + " dimes \n" +
                    "\t" + nickles + " nickels \n");
                    "\t" + numPennies + " pennies";

            }

            //Checks to see if the amount paid is equal to the amount owed
            if (AmtDue.compareTo(AmtPaid)== 0){
                    System.out.println("Your balance has been paid. Thank you for your business.");
            }


    }
```

Comment: Use a Debugger to find out what is happend

Comment: You showed us your expected result, but what is your result right now when you execute the programm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there, you got a bit mixed up with cBal and dBal. And the conversion of change to their .XX value.

The correct version is below

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;


public class CorrectChange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        BigDecimal AmtDue;      
        BigDecimal AmtPaid;


        NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

        //User enters the amount that the customer owes
        System.out.println("Enter the amount below that is due to be paid.");
        System.out.print("$");
            AmtDue = input.nextBigDecimal();

            //Converts user's input into the currency format
            AmtDue = AmtDue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                double dAmtDue = AmtDue.doubleValue();
                    String eAmtDue = n.format(dAmtDue);

        //User enters the amount that the customer paid     
        System.out.println("Enter the amount below that has been paid.");
        System.out.print("$");
            AmtPaid = input.nextBigDecimal();

            //Converts user's input into the currency format
            AmtPaid = AmtPaid.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                double dAmtPaid = AmtPaid.doubleValue();
                    String eAmtPaid = n.format(dAmtPaid);

            //Checks to see if the amount paid is more than the amount owed
            if (AmtDue.compareTo(AmtPaid)> 0){
                double dBal = AmtDue.subtract(AmtPaid).doubleValue();
                String eBal = n.format(dBal);
                System.out.println("You still owe: " + eBal.toString());
            }

            //Checks to see if the amount owed is more than the amount paid
            if (AmtDue.compareTo(AmtPaid)< 0){
                double dBal = AmtPaid.subtract(AmtDue).doubleValue();
                String eBal = n.format(dBal);


                    int DolBills = (int) (dBal / 1);
                    dBal = dBal % 1.0;

                    int quarters = (int) (dBal / .25);
                    dBal = dBal % .25;

                    int dimes = (int) (dBal / .10);
                    dBal = dBal % .10;

                    int nickles = (int) (dBal / .05);
                    dBal = dBal % .05;

                    int numPennies = (int) (dBal / .01);
                    //dBal = dBal % 0.01;

                System.out.println("You owe a balance of " + eAmtDue.toString() + ". Since you paid the amount of " + eAmtPaid.toString() + " your change is " + eBal.toString());
                System.out.println("Your change amount is as follows:\n" +
                    "\t" + DolBills + " $1 dollar bills \n" +
                    "\t" + quarters + " quarters \n" +
                    "\t" + dimes + " dimes \n" +
                    "\t" + nickles + " nickels \n" +
                    "\t" + numPennies + " pennies");

            }

            //Checks to see if the amount paid is equal to the amount owed
            if (AmtDue.compareTo(AmtPaid)== 0){
                    System.out.println("Your balance has been paid. Thank you for your business.");
            }

    }
    }
```

You should definitely read up on java naming and coding conventions.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh_D. Your solution was exactly what I needed! It works perfectly. Like I said I am very new to Java, and programming in general. I would love to know what naming and coding conventions mistakes I have made.

Comment: A few things off the top of my head, AmtPaid - not a good variable name, should be amtPaid, another example NumberFormat n. Also it would be wise to split up the method to various smaller methods. And you could probably optimize the number of variables used to store data. Google a bit about java conventions you should get a old sun doc.

Comment: Thanks again Yogesh_D. After you mentioned it I went back today and realized what you were saying for AmtPaid and NumberFormat. Thanks for the help and advice.